# .net mvc 3 passing related classes from the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

God my head is killing me.

Ok I have a controller where i want to pass nested data to the view. Which I am doing like so:

```
namespace helpme.mvc.Controllers
{ 
  public class CategoryController : Controller
  {
    private HelpMeContext db = new HelpMeContext();

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var model = db.Category.Include(c => c.SubCategories).ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
  }
}
```

But it is not working. SubCategories come out empty even though there are rows in them. Any suggestions?

Using a break point i see that the model is being correctly populated, but nothing is displayed in the view and no error msg.

Here is the view code:

```
@model IEnumerable<helpme.mvc.Models.Category>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@Model.First().SubCategories.First().Name // UPDATE, THIS DISPLAYS A VALUE, SO WHY DOES THE CODE BELOW JUST DISPLAY THE FIRST LEVEL (Categories)?

<ul>
@foreach (var c in Model) {
    <li>
            <ul>
            @foreach (var sc in c.SubCategories)
            {
                @Html.Display(sc.Name)

                foreach (var ssc in sc.SubSubCategories)
                 {
                     @Html.Display(ssc.Name)
                 }
            }
            </ul>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

For some reason it only displays the first level, as if it did not receive the SubCategories, even though the break-point proves that it did.

And here is the model, just for reference:

```
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        SubCategories = new List<SubCategory>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategory
{
    public SubCategory()
    {
        SubSubCategories = new List<SubSubCategory>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SubSubCategory> SubSubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When you set a breakpoint on your `return` statement, does `model` have the expected value?

Comment: Yes it displays 1 object in the first and 2 in the next.

Comment: interesting that it does.. that just puzzles me even more, now i have no idea why my data is not shown

Comment: Can you post your Index View's entire code?

Comment: as per @p.campbell's request i've updated the question

Comment: try to updated edmx file

Comment: MY GOD, I just added @Model.First().SubCategories.First().Name to the view just to make sure it was not receiving the data.. and it displayed a value! I'll go crazy before i figure this out. Apparently all my data is passed to my view? So what? It there something wrong with my foreachs?

Comment: Interesting problem. What happens if you try to display the .Count of the Subcategories (within the foreach)?

Comment: Try adding a dummy value in new List<SubCategory>(); to see if for some reason the view is accessing old collection instead of whatever Entity Framework is supposed to assign.

Comment: You would need to `Include()` the `.SubSubCategories` (using a `.Select()` or `.SelectMany` most likely).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps explicitly type define your `model` as `List<Category>`. Suspect it's currently `ObjectQuery<Category>`? Can you confirm?

As you know, your View is expecting a `IEnumerable<helpme.mvc.Models.Category>`.

Try explicitly casting your model to the type your View wants.

```
 List<Category> model = db.Category.Include(c => c.SubCategories).ToList();
```

It's not clear where the root of the problem is: in the data access, or in accessing the objects in the View. Can you load up some dummy Category and SubCat in that method, and pass known good values to your View? That'll help determine where the issue lies.

Comment: Very good suggestion, however it did not seem to make a deference unfortunately.

Comment: Have you had success with `ICollection` before? Any difference when you change to `IList` or `IEnumerable`?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that `.Include().ToList()` is probably not doing what you think it's doing.

SubCategories probably aren't being mapped to the Category objects you pass to the view.

Try mapping them manually with view models:

e.g.

```
public class PageViewModel
{
    public PageViewModel()
    {
        this.Categories = new List<Category>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories {get;set;}
}
```

...etc

And in your code:

```
var viewModel = new PageViewModel();
foreach (var category in db.Categories)
{
    var categoryVM = new CategoryViewModel();
    foreach (var subcategory in category.SubCategories)
    {
        categoryVM.SubCategories.Add(....      
    }
}
```

...etc

Do only one level first (to SubCategory) to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
@Html.Display(sc.Name)
```

with

```
@sc.Name
```

Also please remember you can always put breakpoints in view code, and see how the rendering goes.
Hope you find this useful.
-Zs